# hasNextLine() while loop not exiting

Tags: java, while-loop, java.util.scanner

I understand that I need to use hasNextLine() to advance the line - but when i made a reference to hasNextLine(), I'm not sure why it is still not exiting the while loop:

I'm using a scanner here (sc) to read an input file

```
while(sc.hasNextLine()){                            
//read post specifications from line
                            String postspecs = sc.nextLine();

                            //split line
                            String[] postspecs_s = postspecs.split(", ");


                            //create post
                            reddit.findUser(stripExtension(argfile.getName())).
                            addPost(postspecs_s[0], PostType.valueOf
                                    (postspecs_s[1]), postspecs_s[2]);

                            System.out.println("created");
                        }
```

Comment: What is it doing instead?

Comment: it is reading a txt file line to line and storing elements of that file into an array of string. then i use the elements of the array of string to create an object as seen in the last couple of lines. in the end i print created (just so i know how many times it went through the while loop)

Comment: I know what it's *supposed* to do. Since you said it doesn't work, I assume it doesn't do that. What *does* it do?

Comment: its not exiting the while loop - which means it continues to print created endlessly.

Comment: if you print out `postspecs` what does it print?

Comment: im not sure how but when i tried it again (as i left this issue and continue with other parts of the code) it printed out the 3 lines contained in the txt file and also printed created only 3 times when i switched it back... thanks anyways and thanks to the answer and help! sorry :( i would just assume it was a glitch or something...

Answer (score 1):

´hasNextLine´ will only return false if EOF (end of file) char is reached. An easier way to stop reading is to wait for a sentinel value it you are reading from System.in.

So you would have a something like

```
String s = sc.nextLine();
while(!s.equals(SENTINEL))
    //proceed and dont forget to re-read.
```

I think ctrl+z will send EOF to system.in on Windows, on iPod atm so can't test.